# TabActivity Destroy when it use facebook for session

Tags: android

I am using `TabHostActivity` which have four child elements. Last have button to share the photo on the Facebook. When it open the Facebook to make the session then it back from it. It destroy the `TabActivity`.

Please help me it should not destroy the `TabActivity`.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code for us to be able to help you. However, I would recommend you use a library to establish sessions with Facebook. See my answer for a link!

Comment: you should call a Child Activity from TabGroup Activity

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you take a look at the [SocialAuth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) library. Not only is it easy to use, it also contains some quality examples on how to establish as session with your social network of choice. I have personally used it and am quite happy with the options it provides.

Comment: My problem is not the session. It make session well but its destroy the mine tabactivity.

Comment: Please show your code. Also, how can a session be deemed successful when it ends upon destruction of the `TabActivity` that initiated it?